# The functionality of tcl and tclvalue in R

Tags: r, tcl

I am looking at some code in R that utilizes tcl/tk functions. Several calls have been made using both these commands, i.e
`result <- tclvalue(tcl("cmd", arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3))`

I could not find a reference to these commands in the tcl commands wiki (found here: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/contents.htm), and a quick google search did not yield any fruitful results. What is the intuition behind the use of these functions, and how do they interact between Tcl/tk and R?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Did you check the [`tcltk2` manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tcltk2/versions/1.2-11/topics/tclVarFun)?  The Rnews is not particularly helpful, I am afraid, there is no mentioning of basic Tcl/R variable interop.

Comment: The supported commands are probably those from [Tcl 8.6](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm), which is the current production release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like these are documented at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tcltk/versions/3.6.1/topics/TclInterface